# python - using ctypes and SSE/AVX SOMETIMES segfaults

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, ctypes, sse, avx

+
I'm trying to optimize a piece of python code using AVX. I'm using ctypes to access the C++ function. Sometimes the functions segfaults and sometimes dont. I think it maybe has got something to do with the alignment? 
Maybe anyone can help me with this, I'm kinda stuck here.

Python-Code:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
#path_cnt
path_cnt = 16
c_path_cnt = c_int(path_cnt)

#ndarray1
ndarray1      = np.ones(path_cnt,dtype=np.float32,order='C')
ndarray1.setflags(align=1,write=1)
c_ndarray1     = stock.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))

#ndarray2
ndarray2    = np.ones(path_cnt,dtype=np.float32,order='C');
ndarray2.setflags(align=1,write=1)
c_ndarray2  = max_vola.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))

#call function
finance = cdll.LoadLibrary(".../libfin.so")
finance.foobar.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p,c_int]
finance.foobar(c_ndarray1,c_ndarray2,c_path_cnt)
x=0
while x < path_cnt:   
    print  c_stock[x]
    x+=1
```

C++ Code

```
extern "C"{
int foobar(float * ndarray1,float * ndarray2,int path_cnt)
 {
     for(int i=0;i<path_cnt;i=i+8)
     {
         __m256 arr1                = _mm256_load_ps(&ndarray1[i]);
         __m256 arr2                    = _mm256_load_ps(&ndarray2[i]);
         __m256 add                 = _mm256_add_ps(arr1,arr2);
         _mm256_store_ps(&ndarray1[i],add);
     }
     return 0;
 }
}
```

And now the odd output behavior, making the some call in terminal twice gives different results!

```
tobias@tobias-Lenovo-U310:~/workspace/finance$ python finance.py 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
tobias@tobias-Lenovo-U310:~/workspace/finance$ python finance.py 
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a CPUID check. I realize you're likely certain AVX is present, but you should still check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I tink I found a sultion, its not very elegant but it works at least! 
The should be a better way, anyone any suggestions?

```
extern "C"{
int foobar(float * ndarray1,float * ndarray2,int path_cnt)
 {
     float * test = (float*)_mm_malloc(path_cnt*sizeof(float),32);
     float * test2 = (float*)_mm_malloc(path_cnt*sizeof(float),32);
     //copy to aligned memory(this part is kinda stupid)
     for(int i=0;i<path_cnt;i++)
     {
        test[i] = stock[i];
        test2[i] = max_vola[i];

     }
     for(int i=0;i<path_cnt;i=i+8)
     {
         __m256 arr1                = _mm256_load_ps(&test1[i]);
         __m256 arr2                    = _mm256_load_ps(&test2[i]);
         __m256 add                 = _mm256_add_ps(arr1,arr2);
         _mm256_store_ps(&test1[i],add);
     }
  //and copy everything back!
   for(int i=0;i<path_cnt;i++)
    {
    stock[i] = test[i];   
    }
     return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: If it did work with the un-aligned versions of the instructions, copying only 32 elements of data prior to making the operations seems a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 6):

There are aligned and unaligned load instructions.  The aligned ones will fault if you violate the alignment rules, but they are faster.  The unaligned ones accept any address and do loads/shifts internally to get the data you want.  You are using the aligned version, `_mm256_load_ps` and can just switch to the unaligned version `_mm256_loadu_ps` without any intermediate allocation.

A good vectorizing compiler will include a lead-in loop to reach an aligned address, then a body to work on aligned data, then a final loop to clean up any stragglers.

Comment: Good answer. A couple notes: for recent (Nehalem and after) Intel x86 architectures, 128-bit unaligned loads operate at the same speed as aligned loads. One small advantage of the aligned load instruction (MOVPS) with respect to its unaligned counterpart (MOVUPS) is that the aligned instruction has an encoding that is one byte shorter. This could potentially yield a small performance improvement in some cases that are sensitive to instruction cache size. On contemporary architectures, however, 256-bit accesses are more sensitive to alignment (although this might have been improved in Haswell).

Comment: My initial question still remains, why I get the segmentation faults and whether there is a possibility to force alignment on python side! I already enabled the alignment option of numpy

Comment: @toebs: Like I said, the `_mmXXX_load_XXX` instructions require alignment and will fault (leading to your process receiving `SIGSEGV` and crashing) if you pass an unaligned address.  I don't know if you can force Python to provide that alignment, but I doubt it.